# Rendering and post that data JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, django, post

I am a bit stuck here and would like to get some input from the community.

So I have a HTML page that contains a table, one of the columns is solely populated with checkboxes, underneath this table is my pseudo 'submit' button, when this is clicked it will scan the table and get the keys of any checked checkboxes this is all fine.

The part I cannot get to work is with this rendered data I wish to post (move it) to another page/template.

What I have tried:

- To do this I have tried posting the data to a view using AJAX (which
  worked) but I then realised and read that I could not redirect and
  render a new template in my AJAX call.
- A form with an invisible field. I set the button to an actual submit button and when the data was rendered I plugged it into the forms field. The logic was all fine however I couldn't get it to redirect, 'action="myurl/"' just changed the URL but kept the same template, it ignored the urls.py file telling it to load a new view+template
- I also tried to post through JQuery but this gave me a CSRF error even with the token and CSRFgetCookie.js (I'm probably missing something here so tell me if I am) but I also couldn't figure how to post the rendered data.

Thanks for reading, any pointers and ideas that you can share will be greatly appreciated

EDIT: note, I want to make it clear what I want to do with the data, the checkboxes represent objects with variables that you wish to print, so if you wish to print it you would check the box and click the button which would post the PKs of the objects to the view, in there you would render the 'print form' (the styled page to print the object) and then redirect to a new template which shows the user the 'print forms' for the objects they selected from here they confirm they wish to print and that's it.

EDIT2: (Code for attempted invisible field solution)

```
<form id="passer" method="POST" action="{% url 'Sizer:printView' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="hidden" id="vals">
    <input type="button" value="Print all selected items" id="printBut"></button>
</form>
```

In the action field I also tried ='printview/' all just changed url but did not render new page.

URL Code:

```
app_name  = 'Sizer'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.mainView, name='home'),
    url(r'^printables/', views.dataView, name='printables'),
    url(r'ajax$', views.ajax, name='ajax'),
    url(r'renderprint$', views.render_print_data, name='render_print_data'),
    url(r'printables/printview/$', views.printView, name='printView'),
]
```

Views Code:

Rendering page (and form) from this view:

```
def dataView(request):
    logging.basicConfig(filename='datalogger.log',level=logging.DEBUG)
    qs = {}
    qs = HeatExchanger.objects.all().order_by('date_created').reverse()

    try:
        data = [display_data(x) for x in qs if x is not None]
        pks = [q.pk for q in qs if q is not None]
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(e)

    template = "Sizer/printables.html"
    context = {'data':data, 'pks':pks, 'form':form}
    return render(request,template,context)
```

View I'm posting the data to:

```
def printView(request):
   print("Inside print View")
   to_print = str(request.POST.get('extendo', ''))
   template = "Sizer/printview.html"
   context = {'to_print':to_print}
   return render(request, template, context)
```

This view is written for a different posting method. From what trixn said I assume I'm looking to mostly change this.

Comment: Good explanation, but _"code says more than a thousand words"_ someone maybe said sometime.

Comment: The solution with hidden form fields is the way to go. If you have issues defining your urls correctly post that code instead an we can help you with this.

Comment: @urbz Haha true, but I felt like noone would really gain anything from my code over the explanation, if you wish to see something which you may draw conclusions from I'd be happy to post.

Comment: @trixn posting the form code now!

Comment: You have to create a form view with a form and render that form. Then when the form data gets posted to your view you have to respond with a [redirect response](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) to a view that shows the objects depending on the form data you passed with it.

Comment: @trixn If I post my views current code could you write an answer to show an outline of what I should be looking for? This would be greatly helpful. I'll post my current view (bare in mind it has been written for an ajax function over this form)